# Stored Procedure create Pivot Table using a Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table  Survey_Data_Response  that is populated with an 'insert into' statement from two tables - Survey_Question and Survey_Response, they are joined on the QuestionID.

I want to use a SP to pivot the Survey_Data_Response table and save the results to a temp table so I can query it to develop reports.

The Survey_Data_Response table has fields - QuestionID, ResponseID, Question, Response, ResponseDateTime,moduleID.

The number of questions can change depending on the survey.

```
 QuestionID   Question   Response    ResponseDateTime       ResponseID   ModuleID
 123           Age          34       2011-06-06 18:21:00     ABC            123
 345           Gender       M        2011-06-06 18:21:00     DEF            123
 567           Phone       444-4444  2011-06-06 18:21:00     HIG            123
 123           Age          23       2011-06-07 12:01:00     MNO            123
 789           Postal Code 90988     2011-06-07 12:01:00     XYZ            123
```

I need to pivot the table to look like this, the questions as columns and the response in the appropriate field.

```
   ResponseID   Age    Gender     Phone     Postal Code     ResponsDateTime 
   ABC          34      M        444-4444                   2011-06-06 18:21:00
   XYZ          23                            90988         2011-06-07 12:01:00
```

I've tried numerous pivot queries over the last 2 days but haven't had any luck. This is where I'm at, it returns the column headers, but the responses to the questions aren't being populated.

```
 DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(1000)
 DECLARE @sqlquery VARCHAR(2000)

 SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT distinct  ',' + QuoteName(question)
                    FROM temp_SURVEY_DATA FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '') 
 SET @sqlquery = 'SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT DynamicQuestionResponseID,question,moduleid 
   FROM temp_SURVEY_DATA ) base
   PIVOT (max(moduleid) FOR question
   IN (' + @cols + ')) AS finalpivot'

 EXECUTE ( @sqlquery )
```

Can someone help me understand why this Pivot doesn't work and how to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should give you what you want:

```
create table temp_SURVEY_DATA
(
    questionid int,
    question varchar(50),
    response varchar(50),
    responsedatetime datetime,
    responseid varchar(3),
    moduleid int
)

insert into temp_SURVEY_DATA values(123, 'Age', '34', '2011-06-06 18:21:00', 'ABC', 123)
insert into temp_SURVEY_DATA values(345, 'Gender', 'M', '2011-06-06 18:21:00', 'ABC', 123)
insert into temp_SURVEY_DATA values(567, 'Phone', '444-4444', '2011-06-06 18:21:00', 'ABC', 123)
insert into temp_SURVEY_DATA values(123, 'Age', '23', '2011-06-07 12:01:00', 'XYZ', 123)
insert into temp_SURVEY_DATA values(789, 'Postal Code', '90988', '2011-06-07 12:01:00', 'XYZ', 123)

DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.question) 
            FROM dbo.temp_SURVEY_DATA c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT responseid, moduleid, responsedatetime, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select question, response, responsedatetime, responseid, moduleid
                from temp_SURVEY_DATA
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(response)
                for question IN(' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Results:

```
responseid    moduleid  responsedatetime        Age Gender  Phone       Postal Code
ABC           123       2011-06-06 18:21:00.000 34  M       444-4444     
XYZ           123       2011-06-07 12:01:00.000 23                      90988
```

Comment: The challenge is the questions are dynamic, they change for each survey (each survey has a different moduleid). The query I provided will create the columns for each question, how do I get the appropriate response under each question? I appreciate your help.

Comment: this will dynamically get the list of the questions and convert it to your column headers and the response will be associated with each question.  If you add additional info to the test above, you will see the correct responses go to the right question

Comment: Yes, I see it now. Thank you bluefeet. I realized that I provided some mis-information, the responseID is different for each response. That's why I haven't been getting the results I expected. Thank you for helping me to find that. Any suggestions how the query would change. I've been playing around with it and keep running into error. I'll update the opening comment.